# Child components are getting different state versions from Parent state during the same render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-component, react-state

I've run into this very confusing issue with React, so any help/insights would be greatly appreciated! In my app's Auth component (the Parent Component), I'm setting the state based on whether the current App user has admin privileges or not. Then, I am passing this admin state down as props to three different Child components ({News}, {Resources}, and {AdminDashboard}, all of which render differently depending on whether the user's admin status.

Here's the confusing part. All three child components are being created within the same render cycle. However, two of those three Child components are receiving an accurate and up to date Parent state (and therefore being passed up to date props), but the third one seems to be receiving an out-of-date state value (the initial state of null, rather than true or false, as the other two are receiving), resulting in inaccurate props being passed to it. I can see confirmation of this through various console.logs on both the parent and child components. I must be overlooking something, but I can't figure it out, since I thought that if a re-render happens, the state is pushed uniformly onto all Child Components that require it. And I'm using the exact code to create all three components via their respective Routes. Here's a skeleton/mockup of the code in question (have excluded some of the imports, declarations etc... for brevity) :

```
/* AuthWrapper (PARENT component) */

class AuthWrapper extends Component {
 state = {
    admin: null,
  };

componentDidMount() {
 // performs the necessary server-side checks then sets state, ex: if user is an admin then

 this.setState({
   admin: true
 });
}

render() {
 return (

// some other components 

  // News and Resources components are receiving correctly updated props from the state, and are rendering 
  // as expected. Logging their props.admin reveals a true or false value (which is the desired outcome)

  <Route path="/news" render={props => <News {...props} admin={this.state.admin} />} />
  <Route path="/resources" render={props => <Resources {...props} admin={this.state.admin} />} />

// AdminDashboard, on the other hand, is receiving a props admin value of '', as revealed when logging its props.admin property
// This makes the component treat every user like they're not an admin, even if they are. 
// This is not the expected outcome, since this component is being rendered by the same state change as the others

  <Route path="/admindashboard" render={props => <AdminDashboard {...props} admin={this.state.admin} />} />

// some other components 
 )
}


/* AdminDashboard (CHILD component) */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from "../firebase/firebase";
import "firebase/functions";

class AdminDashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    email: null
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  // add admin cloud function
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const functions = firebase.functions();
    const addAdminRole = functions.httpsCallable("addAdminRole");
    addAdminRole({ email: this.state.email }).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  };

  render() {
    // this console.log is returning null, but should be true or false (as it is in other child components)
    console.log(this.props.admin); 
    return this.props.admin ? (
      <div className="container form-container">
        <form
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          className="center-align admin-actions"
          style={({ margin: "40px auto" }, { maxWidth: "300px" })}
        >
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="email"
            placeholder="User email"
            id="email"
            required
          />
          <button className="btn-small yellow darken-2 z-depth-0">
            Make admin
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/" />
    );
  }
}

export default AdminDashboard;
```

I've been scratching my head over this one to no avail! Once again, much appreciate any insight anyone might have about this, and thanks in advance!

PS : I'm aware that using a state management tool like Redux might minimise such issues, but at the moment I'm still trying to really understand the fundamentals of React and how state is transferred and passed around, etc...

Comment: A suggestion, use `null` when defining a state value that is not determined yet, like in the `admin` case (which is currently using an empty string). React always needs a top level element; is this just a copy/paste thing or is your component render missing a wrapping element? Besides that, it looks like it should work, could you share the content of `AdminDashboard`?

Comment: Noted, thank you for the suggestion, that's very useful to know. No, the lack of a wrapping element is just a copy/paste thing as you said, everything is nested properly and getting no syntax/runtime errors or complaints from the console. I've updated the code to hopefully make it a bit clearer, and have included the full AdminDashboard code at the bottom. Basically, if the user is an admin, I should see the admin dashboard being rendered, and if not, get redirected to the home page. Currently, due to this issue, the conditional rendering is always triggering the falsy option and redirecting

Comment: the only difference I can think of between the News and Resources working and the AdminDashboard not working is that for AdminDashboard, the Route path and the prop you're trying to update are the same.  I don't see why that should be a problem, but maybe there's interference somehow?  What happens if you change the path to `path='./admindashboard'`?

Comment: @Seth answer has the key. In your case only use the received `admin` prop. If there was a need to set a children `admin` prop (because it was different from the parent one but depended on it), then you would need to update it in `componentDidUpdate`, when the parent one changed.

Comment: @Seth thank you very much for your suggestion, unfortunately the issue persists. The reason for the difference is because originally AdminDashboard was simply called Admin, but changing the path does not seem to have resolved it

Comment: @Alvaro thank you for pointing that out, my bad... I had pasted in the wrong code for the child component (that was just me playing about with state earlier today to see if it would resolve the issue). I've updated it now to show how it was originally when the issue started. I'm actually only using the props from the parent component for the conditional rendering, and not state (at least not for this admin property which is what I'm checking for)

Comment: On the first render it will always have the initial value, which is `null`. That will render `<Redirect to="/" />`. Is that unmounting the component?

Comment: Even so, it should rerender when the `setState` in the parent runs...so that can't be it...

Comment: @Alvaro A good observation! My initial response to that was to try and set the initial state to this.props.admin instead of null, but the redirect still happens. My thinking was that if the props are indeed being passed correctly, the first render should now reflect this initial child state. So either the props are not being passed properly from the parent, or the second option (which is quite likely) is that I haven't yet correctly understand some aspects of how react renders components, and hence my attempt at setting the initial state to the received props is not actually good practice?

Comment: @DanielCassar the ideal scenario is to set the final value when we define the initial state. But this is not always possible (if it is being fetched, for example), in this case we need to set a "not defined yet" value. Providing a "not defined yet" render can be done in each children or directly in the parent, preventing the children from rendering until there is a "defined value".

Comment: @alvaro Understood, thank you... As you said, here the value is being fetched from a database, however it is being done so in the parent, then passed down to the children. So theoretically, once it is fetched and no longer null, it should be re-rendering all children with this non-null value, including AdminDashboard. But in this case, since there's a Redirect involved, it might be that as you said this component is simply being unmounted before it's ever given a chance to render properly. I will play around with the conditional rendering (probably tomorrow) and let you know how it goes

Comment: @Alvaro you were right, it was the unmounting happening before props could be received properly. I've created a workaround for now without the redirect, at some point I will investigate how to keep the redirect without having this issue. Thanks again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
/* AdminDashboard (CHILD component) */

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ admin: this.props.admin });
  }
```

When AdminDashboard mounts, it is reading `null` from the parent.  But within  AdminDashboard, `this.state.admin` is never updated as not null.  You would need to add a `componentDidUpdate` from within AdminDashboard to make this work.

Why do you need a `this.state.admin` from within AdminDashboard anyway?  Just use `this.props.admin` and your value should transfer down appropriately.  So in our render method:

```js
render() {

    console.log(this.props.admin); 
    return this.props.admin ? ( 
       ...
    )
```

Comment: I keep deleting and undeleting this answer because I'm not sure if its correct lol.  I feel like it doesnt address the issue that "`this console.log is returning null, but should be true or false (as it is in other child components)`"...it seems Daniel Cassar already modified his code to encorporate this answer's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Seth, I had pasted in some wrong code which might have been misleading, my apologies... I've updated it accordingly now